# How to reuse a page in normal website and in an Office add-in with office.js

Tags: javascript, office-js

I want to reuse the page of our website in my Office add-in. Any page showing in an Office add-in must include the **Office.initialize** event http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.initialize, a function which will be helpful only in the Office add-in. What is the best suggested approach for this case? How should I include the office.initialize event in my normal website page if I want to reuse it in the Office add-in. This page is very generic; it doesn't use any of the office.js functions or the Excel functions and it's only for display in the Office add-in and in a normal website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just put any code you want to run outside of the Office initialization function:

```
Office.initialize =  function(reason){
    // in here, put code that you want to run only in the add-in
};
// out here, put code that you want to run always
```

Comment: is it mandatory to have Office.initialize method, i noticed that even if i just include office.js file in my common page, my page loads fast without any issue else i see a spinner runing on my task pane for long time even for very simple page. why should i include office.js file if i am not using any of its method.

Comment: Yes, it's required. We use it for other purposes too, such as telemetry and knowing when the page has loaded (which has implications on Office UX).

Comment: which is required just a reference to office.js or office.initialize empty method, also.

Comment: Just the reference

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an empty office.initialize is also required, at least in some cases (I think Office Online... Especially Outlook?)